# Material ui anchor without hooks

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a menu component that pops open in a table. When I copy the material ui example into the cell in the table it works perfectly.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gitl9

The material ui example uses hooks and I want to change it to a class component and use redux.

When I made the change the pop-up menu does not align beside the the button you press anymore.

The anchorEl attribute is responsible for passing the location of the button that has been called.

I added these attributes allow me to move the menu pop but it does not align with button that you click to open the menu.

```
const options = ["View", "Edit", "Delete"];

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;

class ActionsOptionMenu extends Component {
  state = { anchorEl: null };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IconButton
          aria-label='more'
          aria-controls='long-menu'
          aria-haspopup='true'
        >
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          getContentAnchorEl={null}
          anchorOrigin={{
            height: "54px",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            padding: `0 ${padding} 0 ${padding}`,
            margin: "0 auto 7px auto"
          }}
          transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
          id='long-menu'
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={true}
          PaperProps={{
            style: {
              maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
              width: 120
            }
          }}
        >
          {options.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for the "not working well" version?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue doing it this way.

```
 render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <IconButton
          aria-label='more'
          aria-controls='long-menu'
          aria-haspopup='true'
          buttonRef={node => {
            this.anchorEl = node;
          }}
          onClick={event => this.handleClick(event)}
        >
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Popper
          open={open}
          anchorEl={this.anchorEl}
          transition
          disablePortal
          style={{ zIndex: 100 }}
        >
          {({ TransitionProps, placement }) => (
            <Grow
              {...TransitionProps}
              id='menu-list-grow'
              style={{
                zIndex: 1001,
                transformOrigin:
                  placement === "bottom" ? "center top" : "center bottom"
              }}
            >
              <Paper>
                <ClickAwayListener
                  onClickAway={event => this.handleClose(event)}
                >
                  <MenuList>
                    <MenuItem onClick={event => this.handleClose(event)}>
                      Profile
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={event => this.handleClose(event)}>
                      My account
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={event => this.handleClose(event)}>
                      Logout
                    </MenuItem>
                  </MenuList>
                </ClickAwayListener>
              </Paper>
            </Grow>
          )}
        </Popper>
      </div>
    );
  }
```